# Wordpress Plugin wont load css

Tags: php, css, wordpress

My add_action() isn't working and i have no clue why.

This is my php

```
function mapstyle() {
    wp_register_style('mapstyle', plugins_url('assets/css/mapstyle.css' , __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style('mapstyle');
}

add_action( 'admin_init','mapstyle');
```

My css is in 'plugin_folder_name/assets/css/mapstyle.css'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your code to the following. Also ensure that you do a hard refresh with CTRL + F5 or CTRL + SHIFT + R to clear cache, sometimes changes will not show up unless cache is cleared.

```
function mapstyle() {
     //last parameters set to true loads css in the footer instead of header
     wp_enqueue_style('mapstyle', plugins_url('assets/css/mapstyle.css' , __FILE__ ), array(), false, true);

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','mapstyle');
```

Here is [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) to documentation of wp_enqueue_style.

Edit: My bad, half way through writing answer forgot you wanted to enqueue css and not js :D

Comment: Stil wont work! If i look for mapstyle.css in the head it shows its being linked but as a type javascript

Comment: Oh i changed to wp_enqueue_style('mapstyle', plugins_url('assets/css/mapstyle.css' , __FILE__ ), array(), false, false); and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on where you want to enqueue the styles--admin vs. front-end:

**Admin:**

`add_action('admin_init', 'mapstyle');`

**Front-end:**

`add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mapstyle');`

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: yea i tried with wp_enqueue_scripts too but didn't work